# Get input field to appear from option value

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I've got an array of option values called attributionChannels. These values are being populated in a `option` dropdown. This is being wrapped in `Formik` What I want to achieve is that, when the value `unknown` is selected, and input field appears below the options dropdown for them to type in or another way I could think of is making the value `unknown` to be editable when it's selected. How can I achieve this?

```
const attributionChannels = [
  'shop',
  'team',
  'article',
  'email',
  'event',
  'facebook',
  'flyer',
  'google',
  'in_store',
  'instagram',
  'linkedin',
  'network',
  'media',
  'twitter',
  'unknown',
].map(attributionChannel => ({
  value: attributionChannel,
  name: i18n.t(`client.models.idea.attribution_channels.${attributionChannel}`),
}));



  <div className={css.fieldsRow}>
    <div className={cx(css.inputWrapper, css.fullWidthInput)}>
      <Select
        ref={ref => (this.inputs['attributionChannel'] = ref)}
        name="attributionChannel"
        value={values.attributionChannel}
        onChange={handleChange}
        error={touched.attributionChannel && errors.attributionChannel}
      >
        <Option value="">
          {t('fields.attribution_channel.placeholder')}
        </Option>
        {attributionChannels.map(attributionChannel => {
          <Option
            key={attributionChannel.value}
            value={attributionChannel.value}
          >
            {attributionChannel.name}
          </Option>;
        })}
      </Select>
      {}
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: `values.attributionChannel === 'unknown' && <input ...`. If value is `unknown` then render whatever input you want them to type in. This is basic conditional rendering.

Comment: That probably won't work because the OP is working within the constraints of Formik.